Split strings in array, but leads to type mismatch error
I have a string array and I am trying to modify each element, but I get a "type mismatch error"
Dim i As Integer
    
    Dim quotes() As String
    
    Dim str As String
    
    While TypeName(currentAppointment) <> "Nothing"
         
         ReDim Preserve quotes(0 To i) As String
         quotes(i) = currentAppointment.Subject
         
         quotes(i) = Split(quotes(i), "/") 'error in here
         
         i = i + 1
        Set currentAppointment = myAppointments.FindNext
    Wend

I don't understand how this is a type mismatch? I have a string array, and doing string things to it...

quotes(i) is a member of a string array, i.e. a String.

Split function returns a zero-based, one-dimensional array. quotes() is an arrya to hold strings. quotes(i) is an item in the array. You can't assign an array to  quotes(i). If you want to get the first part of splitting, try quotes(i) = Split(quotes(i), "/")(0).

Split function returns a zero-based, one-dimensional array??? Why does that never get mentioned on website online??? Thank you very much TALLER

Split documentation: "Returns a zero-based, one-dimensional array containing a specified number of substrings."

The solution is that SPLIT returns an array, so it needs to be:

quotes(i) = Split(quotes(i), "/")(0)

